# How to make a React component that accepts value like a HTML tag instead of taking it from attributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to make a component in react that would take value like this:

```
<Custom>Hello</Custom>
```

Instead of this?

```
<Custom value={"Hello"} />
```

Comment: you can just access it by `props.children`

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes. You can use `props.children` like this:

```
function Custom({children}) {
  console.log(children); // ==> "Hello"
  return <div>{children}</div>
}
```

Let take a look at this link for more information:
https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx